# Throwing exception for Tic Tac Toe Game

Tags: java

I am new to programming and have successfully made a working tic tac toe game BUT I need to throw an exception so that I cannot place one piece on top of each other. Here is what I have...

```
      /**
      Choose a cell for player has won.
      @param r the row number chose
      @param c the column number chose
      @param player the player who choose a position          
      @throws UnavailableCellException is the cell has been occupied (by either player)   
      */

   public void choose(int r, int c, int player){

       this.board[r][c] = player;
       try {
           for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i ++) {
               if (player == i && player == i + 1) {
               throw new UnavailableCellException("That spot is taken!!");
               }
           }
        } catch(UnavailableCellException e) {
           System.out.println("That spot is taken!!");
        }
    }
```

I can't figure out how to reach the current and previous turn to make them not equal...

Comment: Can't you just check whether `this.board[r][c]` has a value that indicates it was already played? I'm assuming that `board` is an `int[][]`, so just check `if( this.board[r][c] != 0){ throw ...}`

Comment: You need tor check should be whether board[r][c] has already been assigned a player number. No need for a loop here.

Comment: As has been mentioned, there's no need for a loop.  Just check the value of `this.board[r][c]` **before** you do `this.board[r][c] = player;` . In other words, make sure it's empty before you assign it a value.  If it's not empty, you can throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `if()` statement to check if the cell is used or not. Depending on the outcome you set the cell value or throw your `UnavailableCellException`.

```
public void choose(int r, int c, int player) throws UnavailableCellException
{
    if (this.board[r][c] == 0) { // assuming "0" means "free cell"
        // valid, place it
        this.board[r][c] = player;
    } else {
        // already used, throw exception
        throw new UnavailableCellException("That spot is taken!!");
    }
}
```

If `UnavailableCellException` extends from `RuntimeException` you don't need the `throws UnavailableCellException` part in your method declaration.